# Reusing connection objects in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have a function, which loops through over one million records and connects to three different databases.  The language is VB6.  Here are the steps involved:

```vb
public function update(ByVal recordID As Integer) 'RecordID refers to a record in an SQL database

'Connect to an Oracle database
'Do a select and update the current record (recordID passed to function) if necessary
'Close connection

'Connect to an SQL database(1)
'Do a select and update the current record (recordID passed to function) if necessary
'Close connection

'Connect to an SQL database(2)
'Do a select and update the current record (recordID passed to function) if necessary
'Close connection

End Function
```

This function is called many times and I think it is a waste to open and close connections on a lot of the iterations (sometimes a connection to one or more of the three databases is not required).  Is there a better way to do this? I believe there are two ways:

1. Connection pooling (though the research I have done says that it is advisable not to if you are using different providers e.g. ODBC for Oracle connections and OLEDB for Microsoft SQL Server connections.
2. Connect to each of the databases once and then pass the connection objects by reference to update for each iteration.  The job in question takes a day to complete.
3. Create an instance variable in the class for each connection.  The three variables can be opened at the start and closed at the end.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions 2 and 3 are functionally equivalent and only difference is the organization of your code. Typically i would prefer #3. But be carefull about exceptions when reusing connection objects. I am not sure if the state of that object is guaranteed once exception is risen. So take it into account at least and "re-open" in that case. 
Another point is the multithreading but i suppose this is gonna be singlethreaded batch job right?

Comment: Yes, it is a single threaded batch job. It can take up to three days to complete. Isn't it a bad idea to have open connection objects in memory for all this time. Would connection pooling not be better?

Comment: absolutelly not! connection pool is implemented in more or less the same way - it holds the connection until some predefined timeout. connection open/close is appropriete for unit of work scenarios typically on application layer. one goal is to avoid vasting of system resources because connection is not used for most of time or to avoid global connection references in multithreaded applications. for batch job like yours it makes no sense to do open/close.

Comment: I am nearly there. The three connections aren't used the entire time ie. They are only required for a proportion of the recordset being processed. The first and last record being processed could require all three connections. Would option one not be better with this scenario?

Comment: the best would be to split the job into 3 sub-jobs. would that be possible or are the records (type 1, type2, type3) distributed randomly across the source recordset? if so, is it possible to sort them so that you can process type1 first, type2 second, and type3 as last? just to make it clear, by type1 i mean records that require connect1, type2 require connection2, ...

Comment: The records are spread out randomly across the recordset but I am sure I could sort them as you said. Why is option 3 preferred to option 1?

Comment: btw. if nor sorting is not possibleand there are chances that some connection could be idle for longer period of time i think that this is the case for leveraging the connection pool and do many open/closes  in application. simple reason is the conenction timeout which could become very painfull for your app - to recover from the fail. conenction pool handles this for you.

Comment: diff between 1 and 3 is that you can (for example) controll the batch size aka the size of transaction. in  case there are no other transactional requirements (like you are processing some kind of object graphs with reerences)